# Error occured when executing command: npm run serve

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I have tried all the options changes my version typescript from "2.4.2" to "2.4.1"
Also I have separately executed "npm run serve"and "npm run build:watch" but it does not works. I have set the environment vairable but is does not work at all.
please help to resolve this.

while running cmd npm start following errors comes:

Error occured when executing command: npm run serve

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT

```
 at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
 at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
 at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
 at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
 at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Error occured when executing command:
 npm run serve

```
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT

     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)`enter code here`
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

[1] npm run serve exited with code -4058

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch"
 "npm run serve"`


npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-04T05_49_43_912Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented 
with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
"build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

My debug log is :

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]

    2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\Downloads\Desktop\Angular_2\shared_code\quickstart-master\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm

    8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: CWD: C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\Downloads\Desktop\Angular_2\shared_code\quickstart-master

    9 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]

    10 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Returned: code: 0  signal: null

    11 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0

    12 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

    13 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\Downloads\Desktop\Angular_2\shared_code\quickstart-master\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm

    14 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\Downloads\Desktop\Angular_2\shared_code\quickstart-master

    15 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
    15 silly lifecycle   'concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"' ]
16 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
18 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
19 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Nitesh Sharma\Downloads\Desktop\Angular_2\shared_code\quickstart-master
21 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
22 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
23 error node v6.11.1
24 error npm  v3.10.10
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`

    26 error Exit status 1
27 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"'.

    27 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
27 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
27 error not with npm itself.

    27 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
27 error     concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"

    27 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
27 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
27 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
27 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
27 error There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: yes I have posted it

Comment: I just started angularjs .I run npm serve command and npm run build:watch indiviually . After doing error disappeared but when I update my app.component.ts file the changes does not reflect in the browser

Comment: did you check you log ? it will give you error in detail..

Comment: I have check but I didn't understand it as I m new in angular

Comment: @priya sharma Plz format the question , so that others can read easily..

Comment: @priyasharma it might be stupid to ask but did you do a `npm install` before npm run serve

Comment: yeah I have installed it.

Comment: just delete node_modules folder and run npm install again

Comment: @Harpreet I have done that but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, adding the "cmd.exe" to the path fixed the problem, if you are on **windows** just add/append to "**Enviroment Variables > Path**" this line:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: Hello @Googlian, in order to fix the issue I didn't need to write any extra code, it was just an **"Enviroment"** problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve "spawn cmd.exe ENOENT". Go to settings and click on the advance system settings, then click Environment Variables. Click on the Path under system variables and click edit and click new on the displayed menu. After that add this line:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```